# Extension of linear functional on $L^1$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $L^1([0,1])$ with the Lebsgue measure.

Construct a bounded linear functional on some subspace of some $L^1([0,1])$ which has two distinct norm-preserving linear extensions to $L^1([0,1])$.

For example

$F_1(f)=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx$

$F_2(f)=f(0)$

for all $f\in L^1([0,1])$.

We get $F_1=F_2$  in the subspace the constant functions.

Is correct?

But $F_1$ and $F_2$ are bounded?

If not, any suggestion are welcome.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

That won't work as $F_2$ is not well-defined - the functions of $L^1$ are only defined up to a change of a null set (e.g. $\{0\}$).

What you can do, for example, is try taking something of the form:
$$
F_3(f)=\int_0^1f(x)\Gamma(x)dx
$$

where $\Gamma(x)$ is an unknown function to be chosen. If one chooses $\Gamma(x)$ so that $\int_0^1 \Gamma(x)dx=1$, then $F_1=F_3$ on the collection of constant functions.

Furthermore, the inequality $|\Gamma(x)|\le M$ for some real $M>0$ and almost every $x\in [0,1]$ will imply that:
$$
|F_3(f)|=|\int_0^1f(x)\Gamma(x)dx|\le \int_0^1 |f(x)|\Gamma(x)|dx\le M\int_0^1 |f(x)|dx=M||f||_{L^1}
$$
so $F_3$ is a bounded linear functional.

To conclude, take $F_1$ and $F_3(f)=\int_0^1 f(x)\Gamma(x)dx$ as your functionals, when $\Gamma(x)$ is chosen as a bounded function with integral equal to 1.

Comment: In this case $\Gamma\neq 1$. no?

Comment: Yes, so that $F_1 \neq F_3$

Comment: For example, $\Gamma(x)=\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(1)}$ will work.

Comment: How show that $\|F_i\|=\|F_i|_C\|$ with C the subspace the constant functions?.

Comment: You show that  $\|F_3\|=\|\Gamma\|_\infty $, and so the norm is achieved at the constant function  $1$.

Comment: It's not true that the norm is achieved in the constnat function $1$, and it is also not true that $||F_3||=||F_3|_C ||$. It is true under the assumption that $\Gamma$ is a positive function though.

Comment: The problem asks for norm-preserving extensions. But $F_3$ is not norm-preserving?